# Different colors on span inside href link

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to add different colors on span inside the href links. But for some reasons they are not reflecting. Please tell me what is the mistake I am doing here?

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awaises/ye3yp/)

HTML:

```
<div class="map_view_buttons">
<a href="draw"><span></span>Draw From Scratch</a>
<a href="add"><span></span>Add Area</a>
<a href="edit"><span></span>Edit Area</a>
```

CSS:

```
.map_view_buttons{
float:left;
}
.map_view_buttons a{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:3px 10px;
    border-radius:4px;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;
    border:1px solid #a8a8a8;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#000;
    font-size:12px;
    }
    .map_view_buttons a span{
        display:inline-block;
        width:18px; height:18px;            
        vertical-align:middle;
        margin-right:5px;
        border:1px solid #ccc;
        }
        .map_view_buttons a.draw span{background:red;}
        .map_view_buttons a.draw span{background:orange;}
        .map_view_buttons a.draw span{background:green;}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are declaring your `class` names in `href` attribute. Your markup should be

```
<div class="map_view_buttons">
    <a href="#" class="draw"><span></span>Draw From Scratch</a>
    <a href="#" class="add"><span></span>Add Area</a>
    <a href="#" class="edit"><span></span>Edit Area</a>
</div>
```

Not only that, you are having the same selectors with different colors, so the last one will override the two previous ones.

So that should be

```
.map_view_buttons a.draw span {
    background:red;
}
.map_view_buttons a.add span {
    background:orange;
}
.map_view_buttons a.edit span {
    background:green;
}
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ye3yp/4/)</kbd>

Am not sure if you really want the selectors to be that specific, and if you don't want to add the classes to each of the anchor tags, you can use `:nth-of-type()` pseudo...

So the above thing can be written as

```
.map_view_buttons a:nth-of-type(1) span {
    background: red;
}

.map_view_buttons a:nth-of-type(2) span {
    background: red;
}

.map_view_buttons a:nth-of-type(3) span {
    background: red;
}
```

<kbd>[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/ye3yp/6/)</kbd> *(No need to declare classes)*

---

You can also get rid of the `span` tags if you want to, by using `:before` pseudo element with `pointer-events: none;`.

```
.map_view_buttons {
    float:left;
}
.map_view_buttons a {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:3px 10px;
    border-radius:4px;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;
    border:1px solid #a8a8a8;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#000;
    font-size:12px;
}
.map_view_buttons a:before {
    content: "";
    display:inline-block;
    width:18px;
    height:18px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin-right:5px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
}
.map_view_buttons a:nth-of-type(1):before {
    background: red;
}
.map_view_buttons a:nth-of-type(2):before {
    background: orange;
}
.map_view_buttons a:nth-of-type(3):before {
    background: green;
}
```

<kbd>[**Demo 3**](http://jsfiddle.net/ye3yp/7/)</kbd> *(No `span` tags, no `class` defined)*

I am just saying that you can use it but doesn't mean you should use it, just go with what suits your requirements the best.

> Note: `:nth-of-type()` pseudo is not supported < IE9 so if you are
>   looking to support vintage versions, than declaring classes for each
>   is a better option.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS selectors are referencing a `href` value as if it was set as the `class`

Either change your HTML to:

```
<div class="map_view_buttons"> <a class="draw"><span></span>Draw From Scratch</a>
 <a class="add"><span></span>Add Area</a>
 <a class="edit"><span></span>Edit Area</a>
</div>
```

Or, change your CSS to:

```
.map_view_buttons {
    float:left;
}
.map_view_buttons a {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:3px 10px;
    border-radius:4px;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;
    border:1px solid #a8a8a8;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#000;
    font-size:12px;
}
.map_view_buttons a span {
    display:inline-block;
    width:18px;
    height:18px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin-right:5px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
}
.map_view_buttons a[href=draw] span {
    background:red;
}
.map_view_buttons a[href=draw] span {
    background:orange;
}
.map_view_buttons a[href=draw] span {
    background:green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you do not use the span inside the link rather use the parent div as an identifyier then use the nth child selector on the anchor tags

```
map_view_buttons a:nth-child(3) {  
  background:green;
}
```

http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/

Answer (score 0):

'draw' is not a class. If you want to target the href attribute of a anchor tag, this is how you do it:

```
.map_view_buttons a[href="draw"] span{background:red;}
```

Here is the jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/ye3yp/3/

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this fiddle [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abinaya91/ye3yp/5/)
You can use CSS attribute selectors to select a link with href attribute

```
.map_view_buttons a[href="draw"]{background:red;}
.map_view_buttons a[href="add"]{background:orange;}
.map_view_buttons a[href="edit"]{background:green;}
```